# How to get text from a textView in Haskell

Tags: haskell, user-interface, gtk

How do you get text from a textView in Haskell?

I am not sure  I am doing it right. The only "get" function I could find in the TextView class is textViewGetBuffer which evaluates to an IO TextBuffer, not a string.

I am trying to get the string value of the IO TextBuffer using textBufferGetText :: self -> TextIter -> TextIter -> Bool -> String, but cannot figure out what to specify as the TextIter values.

The TextIter values specify the start and end of the range to get text, but when I looked up the TextIter datatype it did not specify any value constructors I could use.

```
    name = textBufferGetText (textViewGetBuffer txtView) start end True
```

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I don't know how to use GTK in Haskell and I can't install it on this machine, so I can't test this)

Looking at the documentation, there are several methods to get a `TextIter` value from a `TextBufferClass`.  The ones you're probably interested in are the `textBufferGetStartIter` and `textBufferGetEndIter`, which each take a `TextBufferClass` and return `IO TextIter`, so you could write a function something like

```hs
textViewGetValue :: TextViewClass self => self -> IO String
textViewGetValue tv = do
    buf <- textViewGetBuffer tv
    start <- textBufferGetStartIter buf
    end <- textBufferGetEndIter buf
    value <- textBufferGetText buf start end True
    return value
```

which should work.  Technically, the last two lines could just be `textBufferGetText buf start end True`, but I think this makes it a bit more clear what is happening.

**EDIT:** I should say that I found these methods in `Graphics.UI.Gtk.Multiline.TextView`, `Graphics.UI.Gtk.Multiline.TextBuffer`, and `Graphics.UI.Gtk.Multiline.TextIter`, so you may have to import those as well.  But I don't know what all is already in your namespace.

Comment: @user1691145 Cool, good to know that for once I wrote code that worked without having been tested or having ever used the library before.  I just clicked the links to find out the definitions of each type, then looked for functions with names and type signatures that looked likely.  It's amazing how much you can figure out with ctrl+f =)

Comment: Why is this function not already implemented in the library, I wonder? Seems to me like quite a basic think you want to be able to do.